# Misalign between OP's avatar and editor's avatar

Tags: bug, design

[An edited question in ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/275268/80007):

[image]

[An edited question in Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31541/14341):

[image: image description]

Comment: I don't think this is a "bug." The editor and the original author box are both aligned by the top of the box; since the original author box has a fancy border, the name is pushed down a bit lower. If it looks wrong to you, it seems to me that this is just your esthetic opinion.

Comment: while I cannot prove this, but I don't think it is just my aesthetic opinion.